# How to deprecate support for Internet Explorer on my site

Tags: php, css, internet-explorer, deprecated, browser-detection

Based on my personal philosophy of Internet Explorer as a browser and the analytics that say my site is barely used by IE users, I'm making the decision to deprecate support for IE on my Wordpress site.

I want to do this by preventing IE11 users from using the site at all, instead informing them that it's an outdated browser (IE11 was released more than 5 years ago) and that the user should download one of the linked modern browsers to continue using the site.

In 2019, what's the best way to accomplish this? Are user agents still a bad idea, or would they be sufficient for this use case considering that those using IE11 are highly unlikely to be spoofing user agents?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Updated, I'm primarily looking for (modern) PHP solutions.

Comment: See https://www.google.com/search?q=check+if+user+is+using+ie+php, tons of answers on PHP if that's what you're looking for

Comment: IMO you should not actively *block* anyone from using your site. If anything, display a banner or such (can be done purely using CSS/conditional comments) that informs the user that the browser is not supported, and whatever happens or doesn't happen is up to them. If a user can still *use* the site in at least some limited capacity, that's much better than not being able to use it at all.